# How to extract the values used in columns by a Classification model in R?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r

I want to find the variables (and its values) used to build a  classification model?

I came to know that the following code does the same

get_all_vars(model_built, dataset_used_for_building_a_model)

However I would not be able to use the above code as I am going to use the "model_built" alone in the R code and i will not be having the "dataset_used_for_building_a_mode.

Simply put i want to use this "Model_built" alone and fetch the variables used along with the values.